# Something wrong with my usage of tokio select! macro. Process block on the first branch notwithstanding there is an else clause

Tags: rust, select, channel, rust-tokio

I attempt to set up a channel to exit process gracefully by capturing signals like SIGTERM or SIGINT. In order to execute business logic by default, i code like this:

```
    let (t_stop, mut r_stop) = oneshot::channel::<Empty>();
    let handle1 = tokio::spawn(async move {
        for _ in sigs.forever() {
            t_stop.send(Empty {}).expect("stop failed");
            return;
        }
    });

...
    let handle2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            select! {
                Ok(_) = &mut r_stop =>{
                    return;
                }
                else => {
                    info!("default");
                    ...
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

but, which is frustrating, process seems blocked on the first branch.

For solving the problem, I try to read the document on tokio's home page. Unfortunately, it just narrates that else branch wouldn't be executed unless none of the other branch patterns match.I expect that `Ok(_) = &mut r_stop` fails in pattern match until signal has been sent, so else clause  should be executed.By the way, after press ctrl+c, the process exit as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select!` always waits for some future. See [the documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.34.0/tokio/macro.select.html):

> The complete lifecycle of a select! expression is as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 3. Concurrently await on the results for all remaining `<async expression>`s.
> 4. Once an `<async expression>` returns a value, ...
> 5. If **all** branches are disabled, evaluate the `else` expression. If no else branch is provided, panic.

Until *at least one* of the provided futures becomes ready, the `else` isn't even considered. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to use `select!` with only one future; you can always use a regular `match` on the result of awaiting the future.

What you can do instead is `select!` with two arms: the channel and *your entire loop*. That way the loop is cancelled as soon as the channel has a message.

```rust
select! {
    Ok(_) = r_stop => {}
    () = async {
        loop {
            // do your actual work here
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the task doesn't need to do any cleanup, consider using [Tokio's built-in abort functionality](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.34.0/tokio/task/struct.AbortHandle.html):

```rust
let handle2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
    loop {
        // do stuff
    }
});

let abort = handle2.abort_handle();
tokio::spawn(async move {
    for _ in sigs.forever() {
        abort.abort();
    }
});
```

Or, if you might have multiple things to cancel, see if [`CancellationToken`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/sync/struct.CancellationToken.html) might be more convenient than your oneshot usage.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I mediate the doc in a meticulous way. My <asnyc expression> is solely the channal itself, so actually its match pattern may be "Ok(_) = r_stop.await"? As a result, obviously the await call wouldn't return until s_stop send something to r_stop, which cause the block .After some experiment, I realize that neither clause is evaluated, which support my assumption.